# Why are repeated memory allocations observed to be slower using Epsilon vs. G1?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I was curious to measure time spent allocating memory in JDK 13 using G1 and Epsilon. The results I have observed are unexpected and I'm interested in understanding what's going on. Ultimately, I'm looking to understand how to make Epsilon usage more performant than G1 (or if that isn't possible, why).

I wrote a small test that allocates memory repeatedly. Depending on command-line input it will either:

- create 1,024 new 1 MB arrays, or
- create 1,024 new 1 MB arrays, measure the time around the allocation, and print out the per-allocation elapsed time. This isn't measuring just the allocation itself, and does include time elapsed for anything else that occurs between the two calls to `System.nanoTime()` - still, it seems to be a useful signal to listen to.

Here's the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args[0].equals("repeatedAllocations")) {
        repeatedAllocations();
    } else if (args[0].equals("repeatedAllocationsWithTimingAndOutput")) {
        repeatedAllocationsWithTimingAndOutput();
    }
}

private static void repeatedAllocations() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
        byte[] array = new byte[1048576]; // allocate new 1MB array
    }
}

private static void repeatedAllocationsWithTimingAndOutput() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        byte[] array = new byte[1048576]; // allocate new 1MB array
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println((end - start));
    }
}
```

Here is the version info for JDK I'm using:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "13-ea" 2019-09-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 13-ea+22)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 13-ea+22, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Here are the different ways I'm running the program:

- allocation only using G1: `$ time java -XX:+UseG1GC Scratch repeatedAllocations`
- allocation only, Epsilon: `$ time java -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseEpsilonGC Scratch repeatedAllocations`
- allocation + timing + output using G1: `$ time java -XX:+UseG1GC Scratch repeatedAllocationsWithTimingAndOutput`
- allocation + timing + output, Epsilon: `time java -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseEpsilonGC Scratch repeatedAllocationsWithTimingAndOutput`

Here are some timings from running G1 with allocations only:

```
$ time java -XX:+UseG1GC Scratch repeatedAllocations
real    0m0.280s
user    0m0.404s
sys     0m0.081s

$ time java -XX:+UseG1GC Scratch repeatedAllocations
real    0m0.293s
user    0m0.415s
sys     0m0.080s

$ time java -XX:+UseG1GC Scratch repeatedAllocations
real    0m0.295s
user    0m0.422s
sys     0m0.080s

$ time java -XX:+UseG1GC Scratch repeatedAllocations
real    0m0.296s
user    0m0.422s
sys     0m0.079s
```

Here are some timings from running Epsilon with allocations only:

```
$ time java -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseEpsilonGC Scratch repeatedAllocations
real    0m0.665s
user    0m0.314s
sys     0m0.373s

$ time java -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseEpsilonGC Scratch repeatedAllocations
real    0m0.652s
user    0m0.313s
sys     0m0.354s

$ time java -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseEpsilonGC Scratch repeatedAllocations
real    0m0.659s
user    0m0.314s
sys     0m0.362s

$ time java -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseEpsilonGC Scratch repeatedAllocations
real    0m0.665s
user    0m0.320s
sys     0m0.367s
```

With or without timing+output, G1 is faster than Epsilon. As an additional measurement, using the timing numbers from `repeatedAllocationsWithTimingAndOutput`, the average allocation times are larger when using Epsilon. Specifically, one of the local runs showed G1GC averaged 227,218 nanos per allocation, whereas Epsilon averaged 521,217 nanos (I captured the output numbers, pasted into a spreadsheet, and used the `average` function for each set of numbers).

My expectation was that the Epsilon tests would be observably faster, however in practice I'm seeing ~2x slower. The max allocation times are definitely higher with G1, but only intermittently – most of the G1 allocations are significantly slower than Epsilon, almost one order of magnitude slower.

Here is a plot of the 1,024 times from running `repeatedAllocationsWithTimingAndOutput()` with G1 and Epsilon. The dark green is for G1; light green is for Epsilon; Y-axis is "nanos per allocation"; Y-axis minor gridlines every 250,000 nanos. It shows the Epsilon allocation times are very consistent, around 300-400k nanos each time. It also shows the G1 times are significantly faster most of the time, but also intermittently ~10x slower than Epsilon. I'm assuming this would be attributable to the garbage collector running, which would be sane and normal, but also seems to negate the idea that G1 is smart enough to know it doesn't need to allocate any new memory.

[image]

Comment: The problem might be that the JVM notices that `array` is not used, so it becomes eligible for garbage collection, and then the old memory is just reused, while Epsilon might have to ask the OS for more memory. **tl;dr**: This test doesn't show anything.

Comment: That could be it for sure – possibly not a useful test. Just to clarify – are you certain that the JVM is just re-using memory, or raising that as a possibile explanation?

Comment: No, not at all. But the sys time might be the result of that. I'd watch the memory consumption of the JVM from the outside. Or somehow trace memory requests the OS get. There is a lot going on in a modern VM. Maybe also store the array in an other array, so it can't be garbage collected?

Comment: Let's put it in a different way: You want to compare the allocation rate of GC1 and Epsilon. There is a trivial optimization if you do collect garbage (GC1 does, Epsilon doesn't): Just reuse the memory you just cleaned. And there is nothing in this test that would prevent this optimization from happening.

Comment: Makes sense. I'll see if I can improve the test to prevent potential memory re-use by G1.

Comment: I updated the question to include a chart along with some comments.

Comment: G1 can collect garbage, epsilon doesn't. If you want to make it a fair comparison you need to "leak" all the allocated memory, i.e. keep references to significant amounts of memory alive, as would happen in many real-world applications. Alternatively you need to pre-allocate a sufficiently large heap for G1 that it will never collect.

Comment: The costs of allocations are the same for both collectors, whereas the costs of reclaiming are negligible (as I always say, they scale with the amount of survivor objects, but here, there are none). But a JVM which does not reclaim objects at all, has to get new memory from the operating system regularly. Which is expensive and the reason why the main difference is seen at the `sys` time. Perfectly plausible results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Holger's comment above explains the piece I was missing in the original test – getting new memory from the OS is more expensive than recycling memory within the JVM. @the8472's comment pointed out that the app code wasn't retaining references to any of the allocated arrays, so the test wasn't testing what I wanted. By modifying the test to keep a reference to each new array, the results now show Epsilon out-performing G1.

Here's what I did in the code to retain references. Define this as a member variable:

```
static ArrayList<byte[]> savedArrays = new ArrayList<>(1024);
```

then add this after each allocation:

```
savedArrays.add(array);
```

Epsilon allocations are similar to before, which is expected:

```
$ time java -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseEpsilonGC Scratch repeatedAllocations
real    0m0.587s
user    0m0.312s
sys     0m0.296s

$ time java -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseEpsilonGC Scratch repeatedAllocations
real    0m0.589s
user    0m0.313s
sys     0m0.297s

$ time java -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseEpsilonGC Scratch repeatedAllocations
real    0m0.605s
user    0m0.316s
sys     0m0.313s
```

G1 times are now much slower than before and also slower than Epsilon:

```
$ time java -XX:+UseG1GC Scratch repeatedAllocations
real    0m0.884s
user    0m1.265s
sys     0m0.538s

$ time java -XX:+UseG1GC Scratch repeatedAllocations
real    0m0.884s
user    0m1.251s
sys     0m0.533s

$ time java -XX:+UseG1GC Scratch repeatedAllocations
real    0m0.864s
user    0m1.214s
sys     0m0.528s
```

Re-running the per-allocation times using `repeatedAllocationsWithTimingAndOutput()`, the averages now match Epsilon being faster.

```
average time (in nanos) for 1,024 consecutive 1MB array allocations
Epsilon 491,665
G1      883,981
```

Comment: I guess you have enough rep to accept your answer now :) (too bad @Holger didn't post his comment into an answer...)

Comment: guess so! happy to cite good input/considerations from comments in absence of actual answers. ;-)

Answer (score 34):

I believe you are seeing the costs of wiring up the memory on first access.

In Epsilon case, allocations always reach for new memory, which means the OS itself has to wire up physical pages to the JVM process. In G1 case, the same thing happens, but after the first GC cycle, it would allocate objects in already wired up memory. G1 would experience occasional latency jumps correlated with GC pauses.

But there are OS peculiarities. At least on Linux, when JVM (or indeed, any other process) "reserves" and "commits" memory the memory is *not actually* wired up: that is *physical pages* are not assigned to it yet. As the optimization, Linux does this wire up on the first write access to the page. That OS activity would manifest as `sys%`, by the way, which is why you see it in the timings.

And this is arguably the right thing for OS to do, when you are optimizing the footprint, for example lots of processes running on machine, (pre-)allocating lots of memory, but hardly using it. That would happen with, say, `-Xms4g -Xmx4g`: OS would happily report all 4G are "committed", but nothing would happen yet, until JVM would start writing there.

All this is the lead-up to this weird trick: pre-touching all heap memory at JVM start with `-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch` (notice `head`, these are the very first samples):

```
$ java -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseEpsilonGC -Xms4g -Xmx4g \
       Scratch repeatedAllocationsWithTimingAndOutput | head
491988
507983
495899
492679
485147

$ java -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseEpsilonGC -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -Xms4g -Xmx4g \
       Scratch repeatedAllocationsWithTimingAndOutput | head
45186
42242
42966
49323
42093
```

And here, the out-of-box run indeed makes Epsilon look worse than G1 (notice `tail`, these are the very last samples):

```
$ java -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseEpsilonGC -Xms4g -Xmx4g \
       Scratch repeatedAllocationsWithTimingAndOutput | tail
389255
386474
392593
387604
391383

$ java -XX:+UseG1GC -Xms4g -Xmx4g \
  Scratch repeatedAllocationsWithTimingAndOutput | tail
72150
74065
73582
73371
71889
```

...but that changes once wiring up the memory is out of the picture (notice `tail`, these are the very last samples):

```
$ java -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseEpsilonGC -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -Xms4g -Xmx4g \
       Scratch repeatedAllocationsWithTimingAndOutput | tail
42636
44798
42065
44948
42297

$ java -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -Xms4g -Xmx4g \
        Scratch repeatedAllocationsWithTimingAndOutput | tail
52158
51490
45602
46724
43752
```

G1 improves too, because it touches a bit of new memory after every cycle. Epsilon is a bit faster, because it has less stuff to do.

Overall, this is why `-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch` is the recommended option for low-latency/high-throughput workloads that can accept the upfront startup cost and upfront RSS footprint payment.

UPD: Come to think about it, this is Epsilon UX bug, and simple peculiarities should produce the [warning to users](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8232051).

Comment: excellent detail + info. adding this, too – from [Java HotSpot VM Options](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) `-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch`: _"Pre-touch the Java heap during JVM initialization. Every page of the heap is thus demand-zeroed during initialization rather than incrementally during application execution."_